# Table with n * rows and fixed number of columns

Tags: reactjs

I have the folowing code in reactjs:

```
render()

    {const items = Object.values(this.state.data);

return (

    items.map((rowData,i)=>
        <div key={i}>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <div>
                        <tr>{
                            rowData['Purpose'].map((subRowData, j) => 
                                (<td key={j}>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>{subRowData}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>))
                        }</tr>
                    </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>)
);}
```

That give the result (in this case) in one row and nine columns like below:

```
value value value value value value value value value
```

How can I have a new row after every second columns like this:

```
value value
value value
value value
value value
value
```

I have tired by ternary operator like this:

```
rowData['Purpose'].map((subRowData, j) =>
   ((((rowData['Purpose'].length % (j + 2)) === 0))) 
   ? 
       (<td key={j}>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   {subRowData}
               </li>
           </ul>
        </td>) 
   :
        (<tr key={j}>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {subRowData}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
         </tr>))
```

but that doesn't work correctly.

How can I achieve that dynamically?

Comment: Please, provide date example that you would like to display

Comment: Date example? I am not sure if I understand what do you mean. If you mean 
 data then let say example: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  and that need to be displayed not in 1 row and 9 columns but 5 rows and 2 columns. I mean the content is correct but not the format.

Comment: In initial of your state your code looks like this: this.state = {data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]};?

Comment: The variation of data is much more than that but in short as an example we can say yes. But not getting out the content is the problem but formatting that like as I earlier wrote in the question. I understand that I need some loop for that but react is totally new to me and have some trouble on that. The ternary operator gave some result but not what I was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be work. 
js/jsx part.

```
render()

{const items = Object.values(this.state.data);

    const Purpose = items.map((rowData, i)=>
    <div className = 'my-container' key = {i}>
    {
        rowData['Purpose'].map((subRowData, j)=>
            (<td key = {j}>
                <ul>
        <li>{subRowData}</li>
        </ul>
            </td>)
        )   
    }
    </div>)

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {Purpose}
                </tbody>
            </table>    
        </React.Fragment>
    );}
```

and the css part (just an example, experiment with attributes like width, margin... should give the desired result)

```
.my-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: white;
}

.my-container > div {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the best solution this is just workaround

https://codepen.io/indrajeet183/pen/RzKMVo

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: [
      {
        Purpose: [
          "test1",
          "test2",
          "test3",
          "test4",
          "test5",
          "test6",
          "test7",
          "test8",
          "test9"
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const rowData = this.state.rows[0]["Purpose"];
    let i = 0;
    return (
      <div>    
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {rowData.map((_,__) => {
              if (i >= rowData.length) return;
              const test = (
                <div>
                  {i !== rowData.length - 1 ? (
                    <tr>
                      <td key={i}>
                        <ul>
                          <li>{rowData[i]}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </td>
                      <td key={i + 1}>
                        <ul>
                          <li>{rowData[i + 1]}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ) : (
                    <tr>
                      <td key={i}>
                        <ul>
                          <li>{rowData[i]}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
              i += 2;
              return test;
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```